# Returning sequence of hidden states for time steps in Keras

Tags: python, keras

I have this model in keras that make sentiment classification for reviews.

```
embedding_layer = Embedding(vocabulary_size +1,
                        embeddings_dim,
                        weights=[embedding_weights],
                        input_length=max_sent_len,
                        trainable=False)

sentence_input = Input(shape=(max_sent_len,), dtype='int32')

embedded_sequences = embedding_layer(sentence_input)

gru_ = GRU(300, input_shape =(timesteps, embeddings_dim),  return_sequences=True, dropout_W = 0.3,dropout_U = 0.3)(embedded_sequences)


attention, word_score = AttLayer(return_attention= True)(gru_)

preds=Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(attention)

model= Model(sentence_input,preds)

adam = Adam(lr=0.001,decay=1e-6,clipvalue=5)

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
            optimizer=adam,
             metrics=['accuracy'])


 history=model.fit(train_sequences,train_labels,batch_size=32, nb_epoch=5, validation_data=(test_sequences, test_labels), verbose=1, shuffle=True)
```

After attention layer, I need to plot the representation overtime for all sequence of the input review. In a heatmap, I need to plot representations obtained after combining current word embedding with previous build embeddings. Each column should corresponds to outputs at each time-step. Now I just have one float number score for each time step.